# Insert content into php page template from wordpress editor as shortcode or other way

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an HTML inside the custom page template in WordPress theme. and this HTML is somewhere between in a bunch of code so I want to dynamically appear that h2 text 
"Our Best Posts About Coffee"
through WordPress editor and not going to edit the PHP file. 
Is this something possible through shortcodes or any other mean?

```html
<h2 class="display-4 mb-5">Our Best Posts About Coffee</h2>
```

Comment: You can use this plugin https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started-with-acf/

Comment: Okay i solved this on my own
Create a custom field in wordpress page/post , set a value and key, then this code needs to add on the page-template.php

echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = 'homepage_text1', $single = true );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i solved this on my own
Create a custom field in wordpress page/post, set a value and key, then this code needs to add on the page-template.php

```html
echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = 'homepage_text1', $single = true );
```